# "All but not" jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I can select (using jQuery) all the divs in a HTML markup as follows:

```
$('div')
```

But I want to exclude a particular `div` (say having `id="myid"`) from the above selection.

How can I do this using Jquery functions?

Comment: use the not selector in jquery

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Simple:

```
$('div').not('#myid');
```

Using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) will remove elements matched by the selector given to it from the set returned by `$('div')`.

You can also use  the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/1) selector:

```
$('div:not(#myid)');
```

Both selectors do the same thing, however [`:not()` is faster](https://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-native-not), presumably because jQuery's selector engine Sizzle can optimise it into a native `.querySelectorAll()` call.

Comment: @Raynos I don't think it's necessarily _bad_, but using `.not()` is _far, far_ better than `:not()`.

Comment: I think it should be `$('div:not(#myid)');` (without quotes). @Raynos: Why? `:not()` is a CSS3 selector. jQuery can directly pass the selector to `querySelectorAll` if supported...

Comment: @FelixKling it's fine as a part of [selectors4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#negation). However in jQuery it's slower then `.not` and less readable. I should have said ":not selector in jQuery"

Comment: @Raynos: No Selectors spec has ever allowed quotes within `:not()`. Neither is this selector new to Selectors 4, nor has it been changed to allow quotes. It has been changed to allow more complex selectors, though. Unless I misunderstood your comment...

Comment: @BoltClock I meant it's fine to use `:not` in your CSS. selectors4 is a CSS spec.

Comment: I was frustrated by the flicker being caused by my selector hiding all the elements and then showing one of them, this helped me get rid the of the flicker. +1

Comment: I'd really like to know an alternative $('.thisone, .andthis:not(.thisone)')

Comment: `.not()` "faster"? Need correction... Today (2017 not 2011) there are native Javascript `.querySelector()` and [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)  that are faster! And [sizzlejs](http://sizzlejs.com/) is optimized for it.

Comment: @PeterKrauss I just did [a jsPerf benchmark](https://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-native-not) which marks `querySelectorAll` as the fastest. Not a real world benchmark, but to be expected seeing as there's no overhead from jQuery internal. `:not()` is in fact faster, presumably because Sizzle knows it can optimise it to use `querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 9):

```
var els = toArray(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));
els.splice(els.indexOf(document.getElementById("someId"), 1);
```

You could just do it the old fashioned way. No need for jQuery with something so simple.

**Pro tips:**

A set of dom elements is just an array, so use your favourite `toArray` method on a `NodeList`.

Adding elements to a set is just

`set.push.apply(set, arrOfElements);`

Removing an element from a set is

`set.splice(set.indexOf(el), 1)`

You can't easily remove multiple elements at once :(

Comment: In nowadays (2017) perhaps the use of native Javascript `.querySelector()` or [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with  `div:not(#myid)`  **is faster**... Is it?

Answer (score 8):

```
$("div:not(#myid)")
```

<sup>[[doc]](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)</sup>

or

```
$("div").not("#myid")
```

<sup>[[doc]](http://api.jquery.com/not/)</sup>

are main ways to select all but one id

You can see [demo here](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/21533/9)

Comment: Today (2017) perhaps `$("div:not(#myid)")`  **is faster**... Check [sizzlejs](http://sizzlejs.com/) optimization for it, when using native Javascript `.querySelector()` or [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 6):

```
   var elements =  $('div').not('#myid');
```

This will include all the divs except the one with id 'myid'

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div:not(#myid)');
```

this is what you need i think.

Answer (score 3):

That should do it:

```
$('div:not("#myid")')
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the `.not` property of the jQuery library:

```
$('div').not('#myDiv').css('background-color', '#000000');
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/w8fRk/). The div #myDiv will be white.