# jQuery check if element is visible in if statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I need a function that displays only one of the selected divs at a time. I have it pretty much working except the if statement. I want the button to hide the div if it is already showing. But it is not working and I cant figure out why. Thank you for your help.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {
    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    if (jQuery('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).is(":visible")) {
      jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    } else {
      jQuery('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</button>
<button class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</button>
<button class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</button>
<button class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</button>
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Comment: Suggest you create a JS Fiddle with this code and link to it in your question http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Create a Stack Snippet so the example is executable in the question.

Comment: You're hiding ALL the DIVs, not just the target DIV.

Comment: I would love to see a JS Fiddle, but in the meanwhile check out [jquery not question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938259/all-but-not-jquery-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your function is hiding all the DIVs:

```
$(".targetDiv").hide();
```

So when it tests whether the target DIV is visible, it's not, because you just hid it. You should hide all the DIVs except the target:

```
$(".targetDiv:not(#div"+$(this).attr("target")+")").hide();
```

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {
    var targetID = '#div' + $(this).attr('target');
    jQuery('.targetDiv:not('+targetID+')').hide();
    if (jQuery(targetID).is(":visible")) {
      jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    } else {
      jQuery(targetID).slideToggle();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</button>
<button class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</button>
<button class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</button>
<button class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</button>
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
        jQuery('.targetDiv').slideUp();
        jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Demo:

```js
jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {
  jQuery('.targetDiv').slideUp();
  jQuery('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</button>
<button class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</button>
<button class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</button>
<button class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</button>
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

---

Edited: replaced the `$(document).ready()` wrapper, just in case it's not *understood*

Comment: This has the same problem as the original. Clicking on a button twice should show the DIV first, then hide it.

Comment: @Barmar Are you sure? Question sounded, to me, like desired behavior was for a `car-radio button` type system..?

Comment: From the question: _I want the button to hide the div if it's already showing_.

Comment: Run the original code, it does the same thing as yours, just with a little difference in the animation.

Comment: *The checkmark don't lie*...  I guess you had it right :)