# Select all elements except - jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

I have this code:

```
<div class="contact-form">
  <input class="form-type-textfield name" />
  <input class="form-type-textfield surname" />
  <input class="form-type-textfield address" />
  <div class="undesirable-inputs">
      <input class="form-type-textfield one" />
      <input class="form-type-textfield two" />
      <input class="form-type-textfield three" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to select all elements with .form-type-textfield class but exclude those which are located in .undesirable-inputs div. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["All but not" jQuery selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938259/all-but-not-jquery-selector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `not()` to exclude selectors

```
$('.form-type-textfield').not('.undesirable-inputs .form-type-textfield')
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it:

```
$('.contact-form .form-type-textfield').not('.undesirable-inputs .form-type-textfield');
```

Comment: quite honestly if you got solution that fast...you really didn't try researching before asking question

Comment: But @charlietfl don't forget [the power of the duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). ;^D